# How to designate where pygame creates the game window

Tags: python, screen, pygame

Is there any way to control where pygame creates the game screen? It seems to always create it in the same general area but not in a consistent location.

Comment: Care to share code so we can better assess your problem?

Comment: After I import my modules, I run this code:                   games.init(screen_width = 908, screen_height = 683, fps = 60)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Positioning of windows is not handled by the client application. It's handled by the Window manager (metacity etc.).

The SDL library on which PyGame is based does have a [few environment variables](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/328286-creating-an-sdl-window-centered-on-screen/) which can be used to give [hints](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html) to the Window manager. These are hints which the WM may ignore but it's the best you can do.

The comments over [here](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.init) have an example.

Comment: OK, well I guess that answers my question. I'm making a game for a final project, and I'm planning on adding in a start menu. When that's up, I guess the player will just have to reposition the screen if needed then.

Comment: Or you could make it full screen. :)

Answer (score 24):

```
import os  

os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = str(position[0]) + "," + str(position[1])
```

as per http://pygame.org/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions

You can also just center the screen with

```
import pygame, os 

os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'
```

Note that these should be done before you initialize pygame in the main loop. I do it right after I import os for example. And since they are not actually part of pygame, you can probably use it elsewhere, though things like gtk and wxpython provide their own mechanisms.

Comment: For the first code it says 'position' isn't defined, and for the second code it just do anything that I can tell.

Comment: Of course. position[0] and position[1] are placeholders indicating what is expected there; a user variable of some sort. 

And as Noufal Ibrahim said, if your window manager refuses to cooperate, it just wont work. In my case it tests fine under gnome with compiz.