# Focused pygame window

Tags: python, pygame

When I start my program that has to open pygame window, it opens it behind the current window. What have I to write to make a focus on pygame window and it won't be as background?

Comment: This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5814202/6220679) seems to do this as a side effect (I'm not sure if it's 100% reliable).