# Python Window Launching in Background

Tags: python, pygame

I've recently been playing around with pygame (and Tkinter), but every time I run my code, the new window launches at the bottom of the stack of open windows, making it very irritating to check on small changes in the program. I thought it may have been Windows Foreground Timeout, but the issue has persisted even after disabling it. I have done a full reinstall of both Python and Anaconda, and can find no other references on Google to similar issues. Issue persisted when run both on JupyterLab and Spyder.

Any advice at all would be helpful

EDIT: I should make clear: this happens with any code that opens a new window, not just the sample given below

- Windows 10 x64
- Python 3.9
- JupyterLab 1.2.6
- Spyder 4.0.1

```
#Sample Code

import pygame
import time
import os  

os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = '0, 30'

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 750, 500
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Crossword Mk2")


def main():
    FPS = 60
    run = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    
    
    
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                quit()
                
                
main()
```

Comment: The window the opens is the pygame screen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814125/how-to-designate-where-pygame-creates-the-game-window/5814202#5814202

Comment: @Halmon - no, it doesn't. I had read that thread before and did not find it resolved my issue

Answer (score 0):

why did you  define `main`? is there any importance? if not, try this code

```
import pygame
import time
import os  

os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = '0, 30'

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 750, 500
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Crossword Mk2")
run=True
    
    
while run:
    FPS=600 # 1 sec=1000 
    pygame.time.delay(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: The short answer is: "the pygame tutorial told me to."  The longer version is that this was the first fifteen-odd lines of code in something I expected to be around 400 lines, it was just making sure a window appeared on the screen before I began doing things with that window.  Either way, I tried your version and it runs into the same problem, the window launches in the background, not in focus.